# SoundManager2 IE8 Issues

Tags: javascript, audio, soundmanager2

I'm using Sound Manager 2 to play a few mp3 snippets when images are clicked.  The links are working fine in all modern browsers including IE9.  But in IE8 I'm seeing a white box and audio is loading in Windows Media Player rather than playing in the browser.  Any idea how I can make this work?

The links are created by a simple anchor linking to the audio file.

```
<a href="myaudiofile.mp3"><img src="myimage.jpg"></a>
```

The page is here.  If I could add anymore code here to describe the issue, I would.
http://bit.ly/1b76rno

Comment: "Debug my web site" questions with only a link to the site are likely to be closed. To avoid it, you should create a minimal but complete example that shows the problem and paste the code in the question. See also [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)